# (change) event hook in angular2

Tags: javascript, events, angular, logical-operators

I know about the (change) `event Binding` in angular2 but i am surprised why my code is not working as expected?

My code is here..

http://plnkr.co/edit/9pSWSeqBc5oaSAtsfwNY?p=preview

When the change event is called not both condition work as expected.

`(change)="holiday= !holiday && employee= !employee"`

When change event is called the first time it works fine but the second time it will work only for first condition i.e `holiday`. In my example what I expected is both the value to be either true or false but not as expected.

Surely there is some mistake. Is there anyone who can explain the life cycle of the `(change)` event properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should separate them with `;` instead of `&&` operator.

If first expression goes wrong, it would not evaluate the next expression.

```
(change)="holiday= !holiday;employee= !employee"
```

> **How `&&` operator works?**
>
> 1. Suppose `a && b`, if both are true then only it returns true(in short there shouldn't be any `false` value otherwise it will return false).
> 2. When evaluating `a && b` code will first check `a` value is `true` then only the interpreter will goes `b` value to evaluate it. If `a` value it self is
>      `false` then it don't evaluate(check) `b`'s value, and `a && b`
>      expression will return `false`.

Before you were having `holiday= !holiday && employee= !employee`. On initial load both `holiday` & `employee` has `false` value. When you click on the `checkbox` it evaluates `holiday= !holiday && employee= !employee`, both `holiday` & `employee` value becomes `true`.

Basically behind the scene when 1st `holiday= !holiday` get evaluated, `holiday` becomes `true` to `false` & `holiday= !holiday`expression return latest value(returns `true`), whether 2nd expression does the same thing & returns `true`.

Now `holiday = true` & `employee = true`. When you click on the check box again. It calls change event & again try to evaluate `holiday= !holiday && employee= !employee`.
Where `holiday= !holiday` return `false`, so then as I mention above **How `&&` operator works?**. It doesn't care about the next part of expression, and returns `false` value.

Now `holiday = false` & `employee = true`. If you click on checkbox again, then `holiday` turns out to `true` & proceed to evaluate other part of expression by which `employee` turns out to `true` from `false`.

Comment: thanks its working now. but may i know whats the problem with `&&` it works but only first time why ?

Comment: @PardeepJain Look at updated answer.still you want any explanation. let me know. Thanks :) feel free to correct grammar. I'll accept the edit.