# ng-if : hide/show attribute. How to do it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I need something like this:**

```
$scope.toggle = true;

<a If(toggle){ ng-click="vm.addFilter()" } else{ '' } >Add Policy</a>
```

**Can I do it as easy as possible?**

Comment: You want to *hide* the entire `<a>` if `toggle` is `false`...!?

Comment: @Decastrio then why title is hide/show attribute?

Comment: @PankajParkar, sorry, i meant difently attribute, not tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add or remove any attribute using angular core directive, you could do something like below. I think you don't wanted to call `vm.addFilter()` conditionally.

```
<a ng-click="toggle && vm.addFilter()">Add Policy</a>
```

[**How `&&` works in depth?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35101638/2435473)

@deceze has good point that there is not need to show element unless it is doing some action. As per that you could also go for hiding/removing the element using `ng-if` as @Serginho suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to do this?

```
//If you want to hide the element use this
<a ng-if="toggle" ng-click="vm.addFilter()" >Add Policy</a>
```

or this

```
//If you want to avoid the event with toggle variable
<a ng-click="toggle && vm.addFilter()" >Add Policy</a>
```

Comment: @Decastrio No, you want the first one.

Comment: @deceze, second one = D

Comment: @Decastrio You said in the comments above you want to *hide the entire `<a>`*. You want the *first one*. What's the point of displaying a button which will simply do nothing when clicked?